# Byte array conversion confusion

Tags: c#, arrays, serial-port

I am reading a serial port and getting a byte array back from it.

It looks like this:

[image]

I believe that data is correct since it was 8:03 on 8/7/18 when I ran it.

Each byte is a value that represents part of the date. Here is the documentation:

> It retrieves the current time and date on the console. Data is sent in
>   a binary format. The format is the same as the SETTIME command.
>   Example (Vantage responds with 5:17:42 am, January 28, 1998):
>
> > "GETTIME" <
> >     <42><17><5><28><1><98><2 Bytes of CRC>

I need to convert each byte individually so that I can get it's value for parsing.  I tried this:

```
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    int length = sp.BytesToRead;
    byte[] buf = new byte[length];
    sp.Read(buf, 0, length);
    var newarray = BitConverter.ToInt16(buf, 0);
```

But that converts it to `13574`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @itsme86 That is the seconds in the time. the index 0 is the ACK.

Comment: You shouldn't be converting your byte array to a `Int16` array, but beyond that, it doesn't look right. The specification says that you should have 8 bytes to a date, but your array shows 9 bytes. Furthermore, the datetime you provided doesn't match the byte array as per the specification (it should go `sec-min-hour-day-month-year`, but your numbers don't match this pattern). Are you sure this input from your serial port actually represents date data?

Comment: It seems like this should work: `var time = new DateTime(1900 + buf[6], buf[5], buf[4], buf[3], buf[2], buf[1]);`

Comment: @Abion47 That's a good point. I'll get with the developers and see what is going on with the data.

Comment: @itsme86 That was simple enough. Didn't think that I could use the bytes directly without some sort of conversion. If you want to make that an answer I'll mark it up.

Comment: @Abion47 It looks like it follows the spec if you skip index 0 to me. I was a little confused at first too.

Comment: thank you all for your help!

Comment: @itsme86 It does but then it sort of begs the question as to what that first byte is for, since according to the doc it isn't supposed to exist at all. It's a bit dangerous to hardcode array indices like that if you don't know what all the bytes are supposed to be.

Comment: @Abion47 I was thinking 6 might match the "GETTIME" command or something.

Comment: @itsme86 I found the [source of the documentation](https://www.davisinstruments.com/support/weather/download/VantageSerialProtocolDocs_v261.pdf). All responses from the machine are preceded with an ASCII character byte representing the response type. `0x06` maps to a successful acknowledgement response. Mystery solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to convert the bytes; you can use them directly to create a new `DateTime` object:

```
var time = new DateTime(1900 + buf[6], buf[5], buf[4], buf[3], buf[2], buf[1]);
```

Comment: ty for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Because your question does not contain the desired data type after the conversion, I used DateTime as data type, so that it can be processed more easily afterwards.

```
SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
int length = sp.BytesToRead;
byte[] buf = new byte[length];
sp.Read(buf, 0, length);
DateTime newDate = new DateTime(1900 + buf[6], buf[5], buf[4], buf[3], buf[2], buf[1]);
```